# Unicode character into CEdit

Tags: c++, unicode, mfc

I'm generating a custom `CEdit` control that allows me to set some different colors on it. It works fine until I generate on control with the style `ES_PASSWORD`.

In these cases, I cannot find the way to write the character I want (big black dot). Here are some codes I've tried:

First option:

```
int lenght = text.GetLength();
text = "";
for (int i = 0; i < lenght; i++) text.AppendChar('\u25CF');
```

Second option:

```
int lenght = text.GetLength();
text = "";
for (int i = 0; i < lenght; i++) text.Append("\u25CF");
```

Third option:

```
int lenght = text.GetLength();
text = "";
for (int i = 0; i < lenght; i++) text.AppendChar((char)"\u25CF");
```

I don't understand why the control doesn't display the correct character. It only displays this: `<`. What am I doing wrong?

## **UPDATE**

Here is the `OnPaint()` method I'm using:

```
void CEasyEdit::OnPaint()
{
    // I generate all requiered objects.
    CPaintDC dc(this);
    CRect ClientRect;
    GetClientRect(&ClientRect);

    // I define which colors I want to use.
    SetDefaultColors();

    // I paint the background and its borders.
    CBrush brush(m_clrBack);
    dc.FillRect(ClientRect, &brush);
    CRect border_rect;
    this->GetClientRect(border_rect);
    border_rect.InflateRect(1, 1);
    dc.Draw3dRect(border_rect, m_clrBack, m_clrBack);
    border_rect.InflateRect(1, 1);
    dc.Draw3dRect(border_rect, m_clrBack, m_clrBack);

    // I redefine the size of the rect.
    CRect textRect(ClientRect);
    textRect.DeflateRect(4, 1);

    // I define the text to draw.
    CString text;
    GetWindowText(text);

    // If it displays a password, I change its characters.
    if (GetStyle() & ES_PASSWORD)
    {
        // I redefine the text to show.
        int lenght = text.GetLength();
        wchar_t f = '1060';
        text = "";
        for (int i = 0; i < lenght; i++) text.Append("\u0053");
    }

    // I draw the text.
    dc.SetTextColor(m_clrText);
    dc.SetBkColor(m_clrBack);   
    dc.SelectObject(GetFont());
    dc.DrawText(text, -1, textRect, GetStyle());
}
```

Comment: [mcve] required.

Comment: `CString` doesn't tell us the relevant information. Is it a `CStringA` or a `CStringW`?

Comment: How can I know it?

Comment: By looking into your project settings and/or build command line. Or by hovering your mouse cursor over the `CString` symbol. [Unicode and Multibyte Character Set (MBCS) Support](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/atl-mfc-shared/unicode-and-multibyte-character-set-mbcs-support) explains the fundamentals.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was looking up [`CEdit::GetPasswordChar`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/mfc/reference/cedit-class?view=vs-2019#getpasswordchar) and I notice it says:

> If you create the edit control with the `ES_PASSWORD` style, **the DLL
>   that supports the control determines the default password character**.
>   The manifest or the [`InitCommonControlsEx`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/commctrl/nf-commctrl-initcommoncontrolsex) method determines which DLL
>   supports the edit control. If user32.dll supports the edit control,
>   the default password character is ASTERISK ('*', U+002A). **If
>   comctl32.dll version 6 supports the edit control, the default
>   character is BLACK CIRCLE ('●', U+25CF)**. For more information about
>   which DLL and version supports the common controls, see [Shell and
>   Common Controls Versions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/desktop/legacy/bb776779(v=vs.85)).

That said, why can't you just use [`CEdit::SetPasswordChar`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/mfc/reference/cedit-class?view=vs-2019#setpasswordchar) where it states:

> Specifies the character to be displayed in place of the character
>   typed by the user. If ch is 0, the actual characters typed by the user
>   are displayed.

Comment: For ANSI programs, `'*'` or some other ANSI character is shown. ANSI programs can be patched with `::SendMessageW(edit->m_hWnd, EM_SETPASSWORDCHAR, L'●', 0);` Notes about `InitCommonControlsEx` might be outdated.